# Rotating an image with respect to its center

Tags: java, image-processing

I am trying rotate a matrix, an image more specifically, by a alpha degree.
I am using a rotation matrix in order find rotate it but if the matrix is not square then the rotation fails and gives an corrupt output.

let's see we have a mxn matrix

```
    for i to m
        for j to n
            new_i = i*cos(alpha) - j*sin(alpha)
            new_j = i*sin(alpha) + j*cos(alpha)
            write the value of sourceimage[i][j] to a new image[new_i][new_j]
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: This does not look like Java? Is this pseudo code? If so, then where is the corrupt output coming from

Comment: You are missing the interpolation needed to transform your output pixels. This method will not provide you with exact values, you need to interpolate them to fit them unto the image raster.

Comment: Also, you will probably need some padding for your rotated image, as your rotated image will not have the same dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the shape of the matrix. You are accessing illegal indexes.